# The puppeteer closes the page after an error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, puppeteer, jest-puppeteer

While testing my page, an error is thrown from the dependency. The error is not critical and does not interfere with my application. But when testing with a puppeteer, with this error, he simply closes the tested page. How can I prevent this to continue testing further ignoring this error?

Example:
This error is thrown on the page and the test ends with it.

```
Error: TypeError: Cannot set property 'paddingLeft' of undefined
    at FrozenColumns.layoutRow (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-tabulator/node_modules/tabulator-tables/dist/js/tabulator.es2015.js:16595:26)
    at Row.initialize (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-tabulator/node_modules/tabulator-tables/dist/js/tabulator.es2015.js:5313:37)
    at Row.reinitialize (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-tabulator/node_modules/tabulator-tables/dist/js/tabulator.es2015.js:5376:8)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-tabulator/node_modules/tabulator-tables/dist/js/tabulator.es2015.js:4415:7)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at RowManager.reinitialize (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-tabulator/node_modules/tabulator-tables/dist/js/tabulator.es2015.js:4414:12)
    at ColumnManager.redraw (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-tabulator/node_modules/tabulator-tables/dist/js/tabulator.es2015.js:1206:25)
    at RowManager.refreshActiveData (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-tabulator/node_modules/tabulator-tables/dist/js/tabulator.es2015.js:3668:31)
    at RowManager.sorterRefresh (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-tabulator/node_modules/tabulator-tables/dist/js/tabulator.es2015.js:3482:8)
    at HTMLDivElement.eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-tabulator/node_modules/tabulator-tables/dist/js/tabulator.es2015.js:22644:27)
```

My environment:

Puppeteer version: 5.4.2
Platform / OS version: macOS 10.15.7
Node.js version: v12.16.1

Comment: Add error in question.

Comment: @RahulL I doubt that something is necessary, since an error is simply thrown from the console of the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using jest-puppeteer, you can specify the exitOnPageError: false parameter in jest-puppeteer.config.js. In this case, the test will not complete if there is an error on the page.